# Spotlight calculator doesn't work (Snow Leopard 10.6.8)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, spotlight

In the last few days the `spotlight`'s calculator doesn't work. It will search and return results, but not the numerical one.

I found only several references to this type of problem, all dealing with older OS' versions. I did try `defaults write com.apple.spotlight CalculationEnabled YES` and removing `Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist` but neither was helpful. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of what happens?

Comment: As I wrote, in general `spotlight` works as expected. When I "search" `1+1` for example then it returns many results (containing something like `1+1`) but not `2`...